# Force Angular2 to update model when a 3rd party changes the value of an input using DOM

Tags: angular, data-binding

Here is the simplified plunker example:

https://plnkr.co/edit/yU9gLsiQJkwsz81H0RBw?p=preview

There is an input bound to val:

```
<input id="inpt" [(ngModel)]="val"/>
```

And some more UI bound to the same val:

```
<h1>{{val}}</h1>
```

If you type in the input, the h1 will change.

The button is playing the part of the 3rd party and it changes an input with:

```
document.getElementById("inpt").value="33";
```

After clicking the button, the h1 value does not change to "33" because the model has not been updated.

The actual 3rd party I am using is jqueryui autocomplete on the input field.

How to force the data binding run (specifically what is needed here is from DOM to model) so the rest of the UI can react to this change?

You will see in the plunker I was trying to use the ngZone to wrap the document.getElementById("inpt").value ="33" in an ngZone.run but I am affraid this might only be concerned with the model -> DOM direction. I've seen some more examples that are also concern with updating the DOM.

In angularjs this model update from DOM could be done with:
angular.element(this).triggerHandler('input');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you do this? Default ngModel listen for input events to do view->model update.

```
export function createFakeEvent(type: string) {
  let event = document.createEvent('Event');
  event.initEvent(type, true, true);
  return event;
}

function dispatchFakeEvent(node: Node | Window, type: string) {
   node.dispatchEvent(createFakeEvent(type));
} 

do() {
   document.getElementById("inpt").value="33";
   dispatchFakeEvent( document.getElementById("inpt"), 'input');
 }
```

Comment: I can and that solved my problem in a very similar way to the angularjs. Thanks!!! Plunker with your suggestion: https://plnkr.co/edit/AFdoi4tT2IpMpBDJwahl?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this in the `do()` method as below

```
do() {
    this.val = "33"

  }
```

**[Updated plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/h4rhOpAQUn8Y3XyH29SR?p=preview)**

Comment: I can't do that. The plunker is a simplified example. The 3rd party is actually doing the change, not me. The point is if a library changes the DOM, how do I force a model update.

Comment: is the just a `ngModel` or `ngModel` of some Child component

Comment: I did not understand your question

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to stem from using a release candidate. The current version works as supposed. [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/tYf4UL?p=preview) you can see it works as expected.

```
export class AppComponent { 
  val = 'someThing'

  do() {
        document.getElementById("inpt").value="33";
  }
}
```

Just works. Things like this are normally detected by zonejs. However, if your 3rth party does something really unexpected, and it does not update in a current version of angular, you can have a look at [changeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html). You can use the `.markForCheck` or event the `.tick` methods to force change-detection.

Comment: Thanks, Sander. It is not working as expected for me. Work means that the label that has "something" should change to "33" since it is also bound to "val". I will research the other stuff you mentioned, but first I am going to try the dispatchFakeEvent below.

Comment: You can also get that done by wrapping your code inside a setTimeout, wich is less invasive. I can amend my answer to include that if you like?

Comment: Does my plunker now work for you? it does work for me in different browsers. If it doesn't work for you, We need to investigate what's going on.

Comment: What changed in your plunker (https://plnkr.co/edit/tYf4UL?p=preview) ? It still does not work for me in Edge and Chrome (I haven't tried others). The <h1> still is "someThing" and not 33 after hitting the button.